# Is every sequence defined on $\mathbb{R}$ just a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be some sequence. For example, $a_n$ could be
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{n}
$$
Can the image of every possible function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ be treated the same as a countable (finite or infinite) subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Well, it is more than a subset, because it is ordered, and can have repeating elements. For example, the sequence $$1,0,0,\dots,0,\dots$$ has limit $0,$ and $$0,1,1,1,\dots,1,\dots$$ has limit $1,$ but the two sequences have the same set of values.

Comment: There is a relationship here, but it is much subtler than “a sequence is a countable subset.” For example, even if $a_n,b_n$ are two sequences for the same set, neither containing repeated elements, it is possible for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ to be different, or for one to converge and the other not converge.

Comment: @mhdadk If you are asking only about the image, then yes, it is already a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. However, this subset does not represent all the information the sequence contains. Neither does it mention anything about the order in which elements in sequence appear, nor does it mention how many times the same number in the image appear in the sequence.

Comment: However, every non-empty countable subset of $\mathbb R$ (or any set) can be written as the image of a sequence. And every sequence  determines a non-empty countable subset. But a sequence isn’t “just” the image of the sequence.

Comment: (An important counter-example is that the empty set is countable, but not the image of a sequence.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that every non-empty countable subset of $\mathbb R$ is the image of some function $a:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R.$ This is true if we replace $\mathbb R$ with any set $X.$

But this does not mean that a sequence is “just” a countable subset, as you wrote in your title. Sequences have an order to them, and can have repeated elements. If $a_1=0,a_{n}=1$ for $n>1,$ the countable set is $\{0,1\}.$ If $b_n=1-a_n,$ the underlying set is the same, but the sequence is different.

If we restrict to $a_n$ with no repetitions, we still have properties of sequences which depend on more than the image of $a.$ For example, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n,$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\ln 2,$$ but there are sequences $b_n$ with the same underlying set which do not converge, or converges to another value.

At heart, a function has far more to it than it’s image.

Answer (score 1):

The range of $a$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, and is clearly countable. So the sequence $a$ clearly *has* a countable subset of $\mathbb R$.  But as @Thomas Andrews pointed out, this subset lacks critical information, namely the order and duplicates. So the subset cannot in any meaningful way be considered equivilant to the sequence-generating function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking only about the image, then yes, it is already a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

However, this subset does not represent all the information the sequence contains. Neither does it mention anything about the order in which elements in sequence appear, nor does it mention how many times the same number in the image appear in the sequence.